# Разделение столбца на равные части и его вывод

Tags: sql

Предположим, у нас есть запрос `SELECT id FROM A;`

Который выдает

`id
1
1
1
2
2
3`

Теперь нам нужно разделить этот столбец пополам и сделать такой вывод:

`id|id1
  1|2
  1|2
  1|3`

Как это сделать? Я пытался провернуть это через CASE:

`select 
 case when id < 2 then 1 end id,

 case when id >= 2 then id end id1
from A`

Естественно, что этот код привязан к конкретной таблице, у которой первая половина значений `id = 1` Да и вывод неправильный: вместо нужного он выдает:

`id|id1
  1|
  1|
  1|
   |2
   |2
   |3`

Тут в голову приходит `NTILE`, который делит(нумерует) столбец на равные части в зависимости от того, какое число вы в него запишите. Пробуем:

`select 
 id, ntile(2) over(Order by id) part
from A`

Вывод такой:

`id|part
  1|1
  1|1
  1|1
  2|2
  2|2
  3|2`

Так, что-то проясняется, осталось придумать, как поломать столбец на два, используя `NTILE`. Тут у меня начинаются проблемы. Можно ли сделать `CASE`, основываясь на значении `NTILE`? Если да, то как и получится ли в итоге у меня то, что необходимо при данном подходе?

Comment: Что за СУБД?  В не которых есть функции на подобие pivot которые из "long" таблицы делают "wide" таблицу. Если pivot нет, то придется скорее всего делать через case -- вот примерно такой же вопрос по mysql http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table

Comment: Oracle желательно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну если ntile, то что то в этом роде можно попробовать:

```
select min(id), max(id)
  from (
    select id, row_number() over(partition by ntl order by id) grp
      from (
        select id, ntile(2) over(order by id) ntl
          from A
      )
  )
 group by grp
```